# Amazon S3 file request error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I am currently attempting to implement Amazon S3 into my rails application but am walking into an issue.

The gems i am using is CarrierWave and Fog.

This is the error i get when i try visit a file/image url.

```
<Error>
   <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
   <Message>Access Denied</Message>
   <RequestId>42B0F41E7EF92ACC</RequestId>
   <HostId>ESYXvkVKxnsu32LjfcsiErZ27IK44ItREPB68sBBHXqWHtzkN9fnc04oj8IzCEFg</HostId>
</Error>
```

This is the url my app is serving to view the image

```
https://vapenz-images.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/product_image/image/2/Capture.PNG?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIEWRNU2VPG5SF7XQ&Signature=GcjA%2Bx46Q9wU%2BuaffhfCTLbLuAY%3D&Expires=1414545697
```

And here is a picture of the permissions.
[image]

My rails app currently can upload a image to s3 but it cant view them, i am quite lost.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: This could be that your are uploading with a auth user through CarrieWave config, but you are accesing without that user( I think you are acessing through web browser )

Comment: If so you could make public that files from aws console.

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean, the app server generate the image link with the access key shown in the url in the original post.

Comment: Do you want public access to those files?

Comment: If so view this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/awsgsg-intro/gsg-aws-file-public.html

Comment: I want anyone to be able to view the files just not delete or upload files

Comment: I just made the pictures folder public, does this allow people to delete/upload files?

Comment: Do you have this `config.fog_public = false` on fog config?

Comment: They are allowed to read only. But if you configure `config.public = true` they shuold be public from the beginning